# Getting kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host from Github Action

Tags: ssh, github-actions, cloudflare

I am trying to connect to a server behind cloudflared tunnel from Github Action in order rsync my project and it's giving a connection error.  I've tried connecting through port 22 without the tunnel by allowing connection from the firewall and can confirm the ssh private key works. I believe it the issue is issue ssh configuration or cloudflare is blocking the connection because I do not see any failed login attempts from the remote server. How can I troubleshoot this?

```
---
name: test cloudflared

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened]

jobs:
  cloudflared:
    name: test cloudflared
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    timeout-minutes: 15

    defaults:
      run:
        shell: bash

    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0

      - name: install cloudflared
        run: |
          curl -L https://pkg.cloudflare.com/cloudflare-main.gpg | sudo tee /usr/share/keyrings/cloudflare-archive-keyring.gpg >/dev/null
          echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/cloudflare-archive-keyring.gpg] https://pkg.cloudflare.com/cloudflared $(lsb_release -cs) main" | sudo tee  /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cloudflared.list
          sudo apt update
          sudo apt-get install cloudflared

      - name: test cloudflared
        run: |
          which cloudflared
          whereis cloudflared
          /usr/local/bin/cloudflared --version

      - name: install-ssh-key
        uses: shimataro/ssh-key-action@v2
        with:
          key: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}
          name: id_rsa
          known_hosts: ${{ secrets.KNOWN_HOSTS }}
          config: |
            Host testhost
              HostName ${{ vars.HOST }}
              User ${{ vars.USER }}
              IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
              ProxyCommand /usr/local/bin/cloudflared access ssh --hostname %h

      - name: test ssh
        run: ssh -vvv testhost 'whoami'
```

Github Action output:

```
OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.4, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/runner/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/runner/.ssh/config line 2: Applying options for testhost
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/home/runner/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/home/runner/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec /usr/local/bin/cloudflared access ssh --hostname ssh.myhost.com
debug1: identity file /home/runner/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/runner/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.4
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
Connection closed by UNKNOWN port 65535
Error: Process completed with exit code 255.
```

Comment: Your debug output suggests that your proxy command "/usr/local/bin/cloudflared access ssh --hostname ssh.myhost.com" is failing. Try getting that command to work by itself before running it through ssh.